# A function overload depending on enum

Tags: c++

Sorry for the noob question, but I cannot seem to get my head around C++'s static nature. The problem: I have a class that returns an enum and depending on it I have to convert the said class using another class and return a vector. In code:

```
enum TYPES { TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE C }

class A {
  TYPES getType() {}
}
class B : public A {}
class C : public A {}
class D : public A {}

std::vector<?> convert_to_vector(const A& a) {
  // depending on what enum is returned by a.getType()
  // I have to convert a into B, C, or D class and return std::vector of 
  // an appropriate type, e.g. int for B, float for C, etc.
}

int main() {
  A a;
  auto v = convert_to_vector(a);
}
```

The simplest way would be using `switch(a.getType())` but I have different return types in each case and using `auto` as the return type doesn't work. I have tried templates and template specification, but they don't accept the runtime variable that is return by `a.getType()`. I guess there must be some simple solution that I'm overlooking here, but I have run out of ideas at this point and would be grateful for any pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve with this solution? Can't you use virtual functions, polymorphism and pointers to the base class? Generally, switching on "type" is often a sign of a bad design.

Comment: Well, I'm using a library that gives me all those classes and the enum. As I said, the base class `A` only tell's me about its type through that function, and I have to convert it into a derived class to get the data needed for a vector. I thought about creating a derived class specialized by the enum, but C++ isn't my native tongue and I got lost in templates pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the return type of a C++ function at runtime.  But you can use a [variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) type:

```
std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>> convert_to_vector(const A& a) {
    if (a.getType() == TYPE_B)
        return std::vector<int>();
    if (a.getType() == TYPE_C)
        return std::vector<float>();
    throw std::logic_error("unsupported type");
}
```

If you don't have C++17, you can use `boost::variant` instead of `std::variant`.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of deciding the type of a vector on an enum a much better solution would be to have a parent `class A` which can have a vector inside it which is based on a template variable. In your classes `B, C, D` you can simply inherit `A` and specify a template type. So, when you create a new object for `B, C, D` you will already have a vector member for those objects. You can also have a virtual function `convertToVec` which you can override in the child classes depending on how you want to convert data into a vector.

```
template<class T>
class A {
  std::vector<T> vec;
  std::vector<T> GetVector() { return vec; }
  virtual convertToVec() { .... }
}
class B : public A<bool> {}
class C : public A<float> {}
class D : public A<long long int> {}

int main() {
  B b;
  b.GetVector();
  //A* b = new B();
  //b->convertToVec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's pretty hard to follow what exactly you are trying to achieve here, going to use `switch-case` is not a good idea, instead you'd better to leverage polymorphism. For example:

```
class A {
    public:
      virtual void convertToVector(AuxVectorConverter& aux) = 0;
};

class B {
    public:
      // Add here specific implementation
      virtual void convertToVector(AuxVectorConverter& aux) {
          aux.convertToVectorB(this);
      }
};

class C {
    public:
      // Add here specific implementation
      virtual void convertToVector(AuxVectorConverter& aux) {
          aux.doSomethingC(this);
      } 
};

 // Aux class 
 class AuxVectorConverter {
     public:
       convertToVector(A* a) {
          a->convertToVector(this);
       }

       convertToVectorB(B* b) {
          // Do code specific for B
       } 

       convertToVectorC(C* c) {
          // Do code specific for B
       }
 }

 int main() {
    AuxVectorConverter* aux;

    A* a = ...; // Initialize here either with instance of B or C

   // Now, based on run time aux class will issue appropriate method.
    aux.convertToVector(a);
 }
```

You might find more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

---

**UPDATE** (Based on comment)

An alternative approach could be to define a map from `TYPES` to some abstract class which will align with the patter from above, e.g.:

```
  // Map has to be initialized with proper implementation
  // of action according to type
  map<Types, AbstracatAction> actions;


  // Latter in the code you can do:

  aux.convertToVector(actions[a->getType()]);
```

And action will be defined pretty similar to hierarchy I've showed above, e.g.

```
 class AbstractAction {
     public:
        virtual void convertToVector(AuxVectorConverter& aux) = 0;
 };

 class ActionB: public AbstractAction {
     public:
        virtual void convertToVector(AuxVectorConverter& aux) {
            aux.covertToVectorB(this);
        }
 };
```

Comment: I'm getting all those classes from another library, I cannot extend them unless I create derived classes. But that's not a problem, the problem is that  my function get's a reference to an instance of `A` class, I don't know to which class I should convert it unless I run the `getType` function. So I have to resort to switch at some point, in your scenario I have to initialize `A* a` with either B or C instance, but to know which one I have to switch on `getType`. At least that's how I understand your code so far. Is that correct?

Comment: ok, in case you have no control on classes you still can wrap them into your hierarchy or decorate them.